# How to implement zipPad using the These tagged union?

Tags: javascript, haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to translate the following Haskell code to Javascript:

```hs
data These a b = This a | That b | These a b

class Align f where
  align :: (These a b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c

instance Align [] where
  align f []     []     = []
  align f (x:xs) []     = f (This x)    : align f xs []
  align f []     (y:ys) = f (That y)    : align f [] ys
  align f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f (These x y) : align f xs ys

liftAlign2 f a b = align t
  where t (This l)    = f l b
        t (That r)    = f a r
        t (These l r) = f l r

zipPad a b = liftAlign2 (,) a b
```

I have trouble translating the `liftAlign2` function though. It takes a tuple constructor and two default values but I don't know where `t` comes from. Here is the code I have so far:

```
const union = type => (tag, o) =>
  (o.type = type.name || type, o.tag = tag.name || tag, o);

const These_ = union("These");

const This = _this => These_(This, {this: _this});
const That = that => These_(That, {that});
const These = _this => that => These_(These, {this: _this, that});

const Pair = x => y => [x, y];

const align = f => ([x, ...xs]) => ([y, ...ys]) =>
  x === undefined && y === undefined ? []
    : y === undefined ? [f(This(x)), ...align(f) (xs) ([])]
    : x === undefined ? [f(That(y)), ...align(f) ([]) (ys)]
    : [f(These(x) (y)), ...align(f) (xs) (ys)];

const liftAlign2 = f => x => y => ?

const zipPad = x => y =>
  liftAlign2(Pair) (x) (y);

const zipPad ("") (0) (["foo", "bar"]) ([2, 4, 6]); // [["foo", 2], ["bar", 4], ["", 6]]
```

I know that the JS code is very inefficient, because it doesn't deal with a functional `List` type but with an array. Efficiency doesn't matter for this translation.

Comment: `t` is defined in the `where` clause. I don't speak JS, but do you understand what `liftAlign` does? When one side is missing (eg. runs out of elements in list case) it defaults to use of `a` or `b` (depending on whether first or second arg is absent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do.

```js
/*
    data These a b
        = This  { fromThis :: a }
        | That  { fromThat :: b }
        | These { fromThis :: a, fromThat :: b }
*/

const This  = fromThis => ({ fromThis });
const That  = fromThat => ({ fromThat });
const These = fromThis => fromThat => ({ fromThis, fromThat });

// type Align f = forall a b c. (These a b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c

// alignArray :: Align []
const alignArray = f => xs => xs.reduceRight((next, x) => ([y, ...ys]) =>
        [f(y === undefined ? This(x) : These(x)(y)), ...next(ys)],
    ys => ys.map(y => f(That(y))));

// liftAlign2 :: Align f -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> f a -> f b -> f c
const liftAlign2 = align => f => x => y =>
    align(({ fromThis = x, fromThat = y }) =>
        f(fromThis)(fromThat));

// zipPad :: Align f -> a -> b -> f a -> f b -> f (a, b)
const zipPad = align => liftAlign2(align)(x => y => [x, y]);

// result :: [(String, Number)]
const result = zipPad(alignArray)("")(0)(["foo", "bar"])([2, 4, 6]);

// [["foo", 2], ["bar", 4], ["", 6]]
console.log(result);
```

Note that `liftAlign2` and `zipPad` are polymorphic. They are not specialized to arrays.

Comment: With pattern matching you can create the elimination rule of each sum type, but because JS lacks pattern matching you use a fold, cool.

Answer (score 0):

A javascript equivalent to `liftAlign2` is

```js
const liftAlign2 = f => x => y => align (t => 
        f (t.this === undefined ? x : t.this) (t.that === undefined ? y : t.that)
    );
```

`liftAlign2` calls your `align` function.

The argument it passes is a function that takes a `These` as the argument.

It returns the result of calling `f` with the values from the `These` if they are present, and falls back to `x` and `y` if they aren't.

By doing this, it "lifts" `f` from a function that operates on two plain values, to a function that operates on two lists.

In `zipPad` `f` is `Pair`, so this constructs pairs of values from both lists, up to the length of the shortest list, and then repeats the fallback value up to the length of the longest.

It's possibly noteworth that this isn't *quite* equivalent to the Haskell code. 
This is because the Haskell code is more polymorphic; it lets you call `liftAlign2` (and also `ZipPad`) on any type which is an instance of the `Align` typeclass. 
While this includes lists, it isn't limited to *just* lists. 
By comparison, the javascript code is specialised to js Arrays.

Comment: Of course, `These` is constructed in a lambda passed to `liftAlign2`.

Comment: I will add ad-hoc polymorphism using explicit directory passing. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I would use `"this" in t` instead of `t.this === undefined`. Same for `that`.